# modalTransitionStyle with UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I had a UIViewController which I was presenting using the UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal style. I changed the view to a UITableView with a UITableViewController. Now I cannot set the transition style.

I get a build error at the line setting the transition style...

> error: accessing unknown 'setModalTransitionStyle:' class method
>
> error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found

Here is the code I am using...

```
InfoViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
infoViewController.delegate = self;
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:infoViewController];
InfoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
[infoViewController release];
```

Do I have to do something different when using a TableViewController or am I forgetting something?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

In this line :
    InfoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

Have you written infoViewController with a "capital i" in your code ? If yes, that's the problem.

Because UITableViewController inherits UIVIewController so I think you set the property modalTransitionStyle.

Comment: Duhh! Thanks. Of course that was my mistake. Sometimes you just can't see the forest through the trees.